# Closed form for $\mathbb{E}[\ln (1-p)]$, for $p \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: probability, distributions, beta-distribution

We know that if $p \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[\ln p] = \psi(\alpha) - \psi(\alpha + \beta)
$$ 
where $\psi(.)$ is the Digamma function.  Is there an easy form for
$ \mathbb{E}[\ln (1-p)]$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Denote 
$$
1-p = q
$$
By the symmetry of the beta distribution, $$
q \sim \text{Beta}(\beta, \alpha) 
$$
Using the identity in your question, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[\ln (1-p)]=\mathbb{E}[\ln q]=\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha+\beta)$$